# Is it possible to cache downloadable files and share that cache between XHR and non-XHR requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching

Here is my scenario:

I have a url that generates a large export of an admin workspace - it's usually about 3mb and takes ~15s to generate.

The current implementation is a normal synchronous request to a URL with a `download` attribute on the button to force a download of the contents.

What I want to do is make it possible to disable the button on click, and then re-enable it when the server responds and the download starts. This is very tricky to do with synchronous requests, but should be easy with an XHR request. The one catch is you can't trigger downloads through XHR.

However, a theoretical solution might be as follows, if it's possible:

1. XHR request for exported data
2. Disable button on click, indicate to user request is processing
3. Cache the data when response comes back (again 3mb of raw bytes)
4. Append the `download` and `href` attributes to the button or some other anchor element
5. Fire the `click()` event on the element for a *synchronous* re-request the data export
6. But instead of requesting from the server again, just get the local cached contents for that URL so that the download starts immediately.

Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work for your use case, but from what you gave to us, I would say :

Request a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Blob) from the XHR, using the `xhr.responseType = 'blob'` property.

Then from the response, you can create an object URL calling `URL.requestObjectURL(blob)`, that you will be able to pass as the anchor's `href` attribute.

This way, you'll get your response cached on user's machine.

But note that this Blob/Object URL will be cached until the user close the current window, or hard-refresh the page, so you have to call `URL.revokeObjectURL(yourAnchor.href)` to release it from the cache.

So some code block :

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function(){
  var blob = this.response;
  yourAnchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  };
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.open(yourURL);
xhr.send();
```

And to the re-trigger click part, I don't remember exactly the browser support for `yourAnchor.click()`, but a `yourAnchor.innerHTML='processing as finished, please click here to confirm the download'` might work.

Comment: This did it. Had to save the blob differently depending on whether Chrome/Firefox or IE was being used, but this answer totally did the trick. Many thanks!